# What's the syntax to create a table type in a stored procedure (using VS2010)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a table type within a stored procedure...my attempt does not compile:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure1
    
AS
        
CREATE TYPE DailyPricingAndVolBySymbolType AS TABLE (TradeDate date, 
Symbol varchar(120), O smallmoney, H smallmoney, L smallmoney, C smallmoney, 
Vol big int)
    
GO
```

I just want to create the type, once, to be used in other stored procedures, I'm not looking for a "reuseable" sproc.

Comment: This question is wrong on a couple of levels - perhaps explain the overarching problem to be solved? If you're familiar with traditional programming languages, it's like asking why you can't define a new type within a method.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks... I was wondering if I even knew enough to clearly ask my question. :) Editing post..

Comment: Based on edit - then why create it *within* a stored procedure? Why isn't plain `CREATE TYPE...` the right thing to do?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You mean within a script then? Not sure how to do that in the visual studio ide.

Comment: I've just taken a quick (30 second) search through a database project (VS2010), and I don't see a specific way to generate a table type - so it would be however generic scripts are written - rather than trying to embed it inside another script (such as an SP body)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Is there a downside or disadvantage of creating it one time with a sproc?

Comment: Other than the fact that a) You can't seem to make it work, and b) SPs are expected to be executed multiple times...

Answer (score 7):

Create the type outside the procedure - it only needs to be created once, and used anytime thereafter:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.DailyPricingAndVolBySymbolType AS TABLE (TradeDate date, 
Symbol varchar(120), O smallmoney, H smallmoney, L smallmoney, C smallmoney, 
Vol bigint)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure1
AS
declare @DailyPricingAndVolBySymbolType DailyPricingAndVolBySymbolType;
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily create a table *variable* within a stored proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure1

AS

DECLARE @DailyPricingAndVolBySymbolType TABLE (TradeDate date, 
Symbol varchar(120), O smallmoney, H smallmoney, L smallmoney, C smallmoney, 
Vol bigint)
```

Or create a *temp* table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure1

AS

CREATE TABLE #DailyPricingAndVolBySymbolType (TradeDate date, 
Symbol varchar(120), O smallmoney, H smallmoney, L smallmoney, C smallmoney, 
Vol bigint)
```

But creating a table *type* within the procedure makes no real sense, so far as I can see. If you *were* to *create* a new type within the procedure, nothing external could know of that type.

---

Based on your edits:

If it *were* possible to define a table type within a stored procedure, then based on other SQL Server behaviors, I wouldn't expect that same type to be available a) to other contexts, and b) after the stored proc's execution ends. That would be consistent with e.g. temp tables, and hence why I don't think it would be useful.

Comment: So I can't create a table type, to use in other stored procedures, pass to udfs, etc?

Comment: If you want to create a table type, then do so - trying to embed the *creation* of that type seems to be the general fault - and I don't see how other procs, etc could be defined.

Comment: I don't think that's the case... you're describing a situation in which the type would be of very limited scope.. creating a type creates a database object. When you need to use it you create an instance of it in any procedure you want.

Comment: Yes, so again, why put the `CREATE TYPE` statement *inside* a procedure? That implies that the procedure would only ever be called once. `CREATE TYPE` and `CREATE PROCEDURE` are at the same level and should not be nested in most circumstances (unless you are trying to create a type to use temporarily, which is not what you seem to be trying to do, and for which there is probably a better solution anyway).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I see that it seems unusual, to be clear I do want to run it just once. I've been working exclusively in Visual Studio, and if someone knows of a way to run a script from that environment I'd be happy to create it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for a table variable:

```
declare @DailyPricingAndVolBySymbolType TABLE (...
```

If you're really after a table type, omit the space in `big int`.  Your procedure will run only once, since you can't create a type if it already exists.

Comment: Thanks... that is just what I'm trying to do, just create the type. Fixing that space didn't help matters though.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to create "create type table". simple example for user

```
CREATE TYPE unit_list AS TABLE (
    ItemUnitId int,
    Amount float,
    IsPrimaryUnit bit
);

GO
 CREATE TYPE specification_list AS TABLE (
     ItemSpecificationMasterId int,
    ItemSpecificationMasterValue varchar(255)
);

GO
 declare @units unit_list;
 insert into @units (ItemUnitId, Amount, IsPrimaryUnit) 
  values(12,10.50, false), 120,100.50, false), (1200,500.50, true);

 declare @spec specification_list;
  insert into @spec (ItemSpecificationMasterId,temSpecificationMasterValue) 
   values (12,'test'), (124,'testing value');

 exec sp_add_item "mytests", false, @units, @spec


//Procedure definition
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_add_item
(   
    @Name nvarchar(50),
    @IsProduct bit=false,
    @UnitsArray unit_list READONLY,
    @SpecificationsArray specification_list READONLY
)
AS


BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT OFF     

    print @Name;
    print @IsProduct;       
    select * from @UnitsArray;
    select * from @SpecificationsArray;
END
```